# How to extract data from a file and then use it in a calculation in Python

Tags: python, file

I want to extract data from one of my files, and then use it in a calculation in Python. Here is my code:

```
def c_p_d():
    d=open("C:\\p_d.txt","a")
    d.close()
    b=open("C:\\p_d.txt","r")
    c=b.readlines()
    a=float(input("is "+str(c)+" the conversion rate of pounds to dollars? Type 1 for yes and 0 for no."))
    if a==1:
        b=float(input("How many £ do you want to convert?"))
        b2=b*c
        print(float(b2))
```

How can I use the data in a calculation? I want to take the data in my text file and multiply that by the number that the user has input.

Comment: It is *very* difficult to make sense of what you are trying to do. Please 1) give us what language you are using 2) try to make your code a bit more concise and 3) be much more explicit in your question. What have you tried? What specifically isn't working for you?

Comment: im using python and i want to be able to take the data in my text file and times that by the number that the user has imputed.

Comment: How is formated the input? how is structured data within the p_d.Txt files? are they line-separated numbers? coma-separated? are they in an other format?

Answer (score 0):

A few comments (and an answer):

- `c` is a list of strings (returned by the `.readlines()` method). If all the file contains is just one number (the conversion rate), then `.read()` would be better because it returns a string.
- But even then, you can't do calculations with `c` yet - you need to do a conversion to a  `float` first. In your case, you'd have to do something like `c = float(c[0])` if the number is on the first line in your file. (With `.read()`, it would be `c = float(c)` - do you understand why?)
- Why are you opening the file in append mode at the start of your function, only to close it immediately afterwards?
- Have you read about the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)?
- You should be using better variable names. `a`, `b`, `b2`, `c` and `d` don't speak for themselves. Your computer has enough memory to store longer variable names.
- You should read [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- You should read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in order to avoid issues with improper indentation like in your question.

Comment: thank you soo much.As you can probably tell im quite new too python  and thats why i use them bad variable names.